# get "convert: improper image header" error when convert gif to png using ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, png, gif, animated-gif, imagemagick-convert

I am using ImageMagick to convert a gif to multiple png data. But I get this error:

> convert: improper image header
> /misc/lmbraid11/jingl/webscraping/dataset_2018_05_18/image2018_5_4_10_34.gif'
> @ error/gif.c/ReadGIFImage/1037. convert: no images defined
> /misc/lmbraid11/jingl/webscraping/dataset_2018_05_18/image2018_5_4_10_34.png'
> @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3210.

Here is the command:

```
convert -coalesce /misc/lmbraid11/jingl/webscraping/dataset_2018_05_18/image2018_5_4_10_34.gif /misc/lmbraid11/jingl/webscraping/dataset_2018_05_18/image2018_5_4_10_34.png
```

The gif file was downloaded from:
[http://www.niederschlagsradar.de/image.ashx?type=regioloop®io=fre][1]

> ImageMagick version: Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Note that proper ImageMagick syntax reads the input before the -coalesce. Though ImageMagick 6 is forgiving, ImageMagick 7 is not.

Answer (score 2):

Problem get solved. It turns out that I did not download the gif file correctly, so the gif file was corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax should be:

```
convert image2018_5_4_10_34.gif -coalesce image2018_5_4_10_34.png
```

In your case, you're specifying the option before files, however it can vary on your IM version.

As per [@fmw42 comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50677948/get-convert-improper-image-header-error-when-convert-gif-to-png-using-imagema#comment88381044_50677948):

> Note that proper ImageMagick syntax reads the input before the -coalesce. Though ImageMagick 6 is forgiving, ImageMagick 7 is not.